# How to create a spl22 token?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, transactions, metaplex, token-2022

it creates a token, the transaction is executed. But in the end the token does not appear in the wallet, why? What have I done wrong?

````
    wallet,
    connection,
    name,
    symbol,
    decimals,
    metadata,
    sellerFeeBasisPoints,
  }: {
    wallet: Wallet;
    connection: Connection;
    name: string;
    symbol: string;
    decimals: number;
    metadata: string;
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: number;
  }): Promise<string> =>{
    enqueueSnackbar("initialize umi", { variant: "info" });
    const umi = createUmi(connection.rpcEndpoint);
    umi.use(mplTokenMetadata());
    umi.use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet.adapter));
    const mint = generateSigner(umi);

    try {
      const result = await createV1(umi, {
        mint,
        name,
        symbol,
        decimals,
        uri: metadata,
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(sellerFeeBasisPoints), // Add sellerFeeBasisPoints with a value of 0
      }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

      console.log("Transaction hash: " + bs58.encode(result.signature));
  
      console.log("Mint: " + mint.publicKey);
      console.log("Signature: " + bs58.encode(result.signature));
      if (result.signature) {
        enqueueSnackbar("Token created", { variant: "success" });
      }
      return mint.publicKey;
    } catch (error) {
      enqueueSnackbar("Error creating Token: " + error, { variant: "error" });
      console.log(error);
      return "Error creating Token: " + error;
    }
  }; ```
````

Comment: You are creating the token and it's overall metadata, but this does not actually mint tokens (create a balance) or transfer them to a token account (transfer a balance).

You are missing two more steps:
1. you need to create a token account for this token's mint address in the current wallet
2. you need to mint a balance of this token to that token account, or to the authority wallet and then transfer it to that account

Answer (score 0):

you can use QuickNode to understand how to mint tokens, transfer tokens, withdraw tokens, and handle transfer fees/taxes of the token using the Solana and SPL Token library.

https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/spl-tokens/token-2022/overview